# Exiting, name server cannot be used: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3) 3 Jul 07:24:03 ntpdate[20133]

Tags: linux, ntp, ntpd

When I use the below comamnd:

```
ntpdate cn.pool.ntp.org
```

I get the below error:

> Exiting, name server cannot be used: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3) 3 Jul 07:24:03 ntpdate[20133]: name server cannot be used: Temporary failure in name resolution (-3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I run into this issue one month ago, in the `/etc/ntp.conf`, my server is a domain name, then I will get this issue, then I give a local ntp server address(it is ip address), then it run normal now.